# Why does a link is clicked when test is run in Selenium IDE, but it is not clicked when the test is run by nunit.exe?

Tags: c#, nunit, selenium-webdriver

I have the following Selenium test:

```
open    /dealerproducts.preprod/MainPage.aspx   
type    id=ucTopBar_ASPxRoundPanel2_ucLogin_cbLogin_pnl_txtLoginEmail_I tester@gmail.com
type    id=ucTopBar_ASPxRoundPanel2_ucLogin_cbLogin_pnl_txtPwd_I    pass123
clickAndWait    css=#ucTopBar_ASPxRoundPanel2_ucLogin_cbLogin_pnl_btnLogin_CD > span    
click   link=Search Contract    
selectFrame     id=ContentPlaceHolder1_tabPages_frContent1  
pause       1000
click   id=grdList_header2_colFilter_2_txtValue1_2  
type    id=grdList_header2_colFilter_2_txtValue1_2  PM10000130
click   css=span    
click   id=grdList_cell0_2_lnkNumber_0
```

When I run this test in Selenium IDE the last link (id=grdList_cell0_2_lnkNumber_0) is always clicked.
But when the following test (which is the above test exported to c#) is run by nunit.exe then the last link isn't clicked:

```
[TestFixture]
public class ElanceTestWebDriver
{
    private IWebDriver driver;
    private StringBuilder verificationErrors;
    private string baseURL;
    private bool acceptNextAlert = true;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetupTest()
    {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        baseURL = "http://mysite.com/";
        verificationErrors = new StringBuilder();
    }

    [Test]
    public void TheElanceTestWebDriverTest()
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseURL + "/dealerproducts.preprod/MainPage.aspx");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("ucTopBar_ASPxRoundPanel2_ucLogin_cbLogin_pnl_txtLoginEmail_I")).Clear();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("ucTopBar_ASPxRoundPanel2_ucLogin_cbLogin_pnl_txtLoginEmail_I")).SendKeys("tester@gmail.com");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("ucTopBar_ASPxRoundPanel2_ucLogin_cbLogin_pnl_txtPwd_I")).Clear();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("ucTopBar_ASPxRoundPanel2_ucLogin_cbLogin_pnl_txtPwd_I")).SendKeys("pass123");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("ucTopBar_ASPxRoundPanel2_ucLogin_cbLogin_pnl_btnLogin_CD")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Search Contract"), 2).Click();
        driver.SwitchTo().Frame("ContentPlaceHolder1_tabPages_frContent1");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("grdList_header2_colFilter_2_txtValue1_2")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("grdList_header2_colFilter_2_txtValue1_2")).Clear();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("grdList_header2_colFilter_2_txtValue1_2")).SendKeys("PM10000130");
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("span")).Click();
        IWebElement el = null;
        el = driver.FindElement(By.Id("grdList_cell0_2_lnkNumber_0")); //.Click();
        Assert.That(el != null); // 1.
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("grdList_cell0_2_lnkNumber_0")).Click();
    }
```

Element id=grdList_cell0_2_lnkNumber_0 is always found when runing the above test because assert 1. never fails. Strangely when this test is run step by step in debug mode in Visual Studio then the link is always clicked.
HTML of the link:

```
<a class="dxeHyperlink" onclick="aspxSEClick('grdList_cell0_2_lnkNumber_0', event)" id="grdList_cell0_2_lnkNumber_0" style="font-size:9px;">PM10000130</a>
```

Can anyone tell me why this link isn't clicked when the test is run by nunit.exe or nunit-x86.exe?

Comment: When you say it isn't clicked, does the script try and fail to click it? Does it throw an exception?

Comment: No it doesn't click it as if the link didn't existed on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I had to add

```
Thread.Sleep(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3));
```

before clicking the link.